# How to call a service through a menu-driven application in Ballerina

Tags: api, wso2, ballerina

I have a file `main.bal` which contains the prints the menu and deals with user input. `gmail_service.bal` file contains a `hello` service which has the ability to send emails.

**main.bal**

```
function main(string... args) {
    int c = 0;
    while ( c != 2) {
        // print options menu to choose from
        io:println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        io:println("1. Email");
        io:println("2. Exit");
        io:println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        // read user's choice
        string choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 2: ");
        c = check <int>choice;

        if (c == 1) {
           //code to send email            
        }

        if (c == 2) {
            break;
        } 
    }     
}
```

**gmail_service.bal**

```
// A system package containing protocol access constructs
// Package objects referenced with 'http:' in code
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;
import wso2/gmail;
import ballerina/config;

endpoint gmail:Client gmailEP {
    clientConfig:{
        auth:{
            accessToken:config:getAsString("accessToken"),
            clientId:config:getAsString("clientId"),
            clientSecret:config:getAsString("clientSecret"),
            refreshToken:config:getAsString("refreshToken")
        }
    }
};

documentation {
   A service endpoint represents a listener.
}
endpoint http:Listener listener {
    port:9090
};

documentation {
   A service is a network-accessible API
   Advertised on '/hello', port comes from listener endpoint
}

@http:ServiceConfig {
   basePath: "/"
}

service<http:Service> hello bind listener {
    @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods: ["POST"],
        path: "/"
    }

    documentation {
       A resource is an invokable API method
       Accessible at '/hello/sayHello
       'caller' is the client invoking this resource 

       P{{caller}} Server Connector
       P{{request}} Request
    }

    sayHello (endpoint caller, http:Request request) {
        gmail:MessageRequest messageRequest;
        messageRequest.recipient = "abc@gmail.com";
        messageRequest.sender = "efg@gmail.com";
        messageRequest.cc = "";
        messageRequest.subject = "Email-Subject";
        messageRequest.messageBody = "Email Message Body Text";
        //Set the content type of the mail as TEXT_PLAIN or TEXT_HTML.
       messageRequest.contentType = gmail:TEXT_PLAIN;
        //Send the message.
        var sendMessageResponse = gmailEP -> sendMessage("efg@gmail.com", messageRequest); 
    }

}
```

How can I invoke the gmail service when the user enters "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ballerina, we interact with network-accessible points such as services through endpoints. For example, the your Gmail service source, you have used two endpoints: a listener endpoint and a client endpoint. The listener endpoint is used to bind your `hello` service to a port and the client endpoint is used to invoke a 3rd party API (the Gmail API).

Similarly, to invoke your `hello` service from your `main()` function, you need to create an HTTP client endpoint for the service. You will be interacting with your service through this endpoint. The modified source for `main.bal` would look something like below. Note that a payload hasn't been set to the POST request since the request body is not used anywhere in the `hello` service.

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;

endpoint http:Client emailClient {
    url: "http://localhost:9090"
};

function main(string... args) {
    int c = 0;
    while ( c != 2) {
        // print options menu to choose from
        io:println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        io:println("1. Email");
        io:println("2. Exit");
        io:println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        // read user's choice
        string choice = io:readln("Enter choice 1 - 2: ");
        c = check <int>choice;

        if (c == 1) {
            http:Response response = check emailClient->post("/", ());
            // Do whatever you want with the response
        }

        if (c == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now I'm getting these errors :         `error: contacts_db_service:0.0.0/main.bal:32:44: not enough arguments in call to 'post()'
error: contacts_db_service:0.0.0/main.bal:32:44: invalid usage of the checked expression operator: no expression type is equivalent to error type
compilation contains errors`

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the code I posted. The call to `post()` should be as follows: `post("/", ())`. I updated the answer as well